# SQL Function to Determine if a Set of Fields Meet Some Criteria

Tags: sql, db2

I'm working with a DB2 database, and was wondering whether a function exists that allows me to determine whether a set of columns meet some criteria.

I can simply use OR to accomplish this, however, I'm wondering whether there exists a more sophisticated way.

For example, this works:

```sql
Select UNIQUE_ID
, CASE WHEN FIELD1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT FIELDS FROM TAB2) OR
FIELD2 IN (SELECT DISTINCT FIELDS FROM TAB2) OR
FIELD3 IN (SELECT DISTINCT FIELDS FROM TAB2) OR
FIELD4 IN (SELECT DISTINCT FIELDS FROM TAB2) OR
FIELD5 IN (SELECT DISTINCT FIELDS FROM TAB2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FINAL_FIELD
FROM TAB1
```

But I am looking for `SOME_FUNCTION` as in the below:

```sql
Select UNIQUE_ID
, CASE WHEN SOME_FUNCTION(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5) IN (SELECT DISTINCT FIELDS FROM TAB2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FINAL_FIELD
FROM TAB1
```

The idea is to avoid stretching out the case statement if it is not needed. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exists` instead of `in`:

```
(case when exists (select 1
                   from tab2
                   where fields in (tab1.field1, tab1.field2, tab1.field3, tab1.field4, tab1.field5)
                  )
      then 1 else 0
 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation.  Reverse the in so its not duplicated into a join.

tabb is unique.

```
SELECT a.id                                           
, case when b.fied is not null then 1 else 0 end as crtieria                                
FROM taba  a                                          
left join tabb b on b.field  in (a.f1,a.f2,a.f3,a.f4)
```

tabb not unique.

```
SELECT a.id                                           
, max(case when b.fied is not null then 1 else 0 end) as crtieria                                
FROM taba  a                                          
left join tabb b on b.field  in (a.f1,a.f2,a.f3,a.f4)
group by a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own function.
Something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckFields (
    @RowId INT
)
RETURN BIT AS
BEGIN
    Code to check row/fields
    RETURN result
END
```

Just google "sql user defined function", and you will find a lot if information.